# How does one generate a palette similar to the ones in Google's material design?

Tags: color, color-theory, color-conversion

Google's material design specifications have [sets of colour palettes](http://www.google.com/design/spec/style/color.html):

[image]

Starting with a base primary colour, which they designate as "500", they then have a range of incremental steps of shade, brighter and darker, to create a range of about 10 colours. The lightest is designated "50", and is near white, and the darkest, "900", is near black, but both retain some of the base colour.

I can't quite determine how the increments are calculated. I tried [this online swatch generator](http://slayeroffice.com/tools/color_palette/), but I can't seem to dial in the range.

I think it's just a matter of adjusting luminosity up and down from the base "500" color, and I'm guessing that a value of "0" would be pure white and "1000" would be pure black, but the ranges in Google's palette's seem to have more saturation than a simple luminosity range.

Does anyone know what algorithm or process I can use to take a base colour and generate a palette in line with Google's palettes?

Comment: They seem to be the base color with the saturation and value respectively increased or decreased inversely as the number goes up or down

Comment: Actually, taking a step back from the screen, it appears to use a similar algorithm as phong shading... I'll have to consider this

Comment: Did you found any solution to generate the palette?

Comment: @MrBrightside Howdy! You can generate a palette using the chosen answer, here: http://mcg.mbitson.com/ - Please note that the colors are not exactly the same as the Material Design palettes, though you can import the exact palettes or generate close representations with custom colors. More on why they're not the exact colors here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32942503/material-design-color-palette/33487476#33487476

Comment: I generate their colors using their MDL library and assigning their respective color classes.  From there, I use JavaScript to .getComputedStyle.  see [https://rack.pub/swatch](https://rack.pub/swatch)

Comment: Material is ONLY monochromatic for the 50-500 range, see https://codepen.io/sebilasse/pen/GQYKJd?editors=1010 for darker and accent colors …

Comment: The link in sebilasse's comment just above is the best "answer" in this Q&A. Enter a different hex value and see the results. Study his js code to see how he does it.

Comment: You could try your hand at the official Google tool for Material color palette generation: https://material.io/inline-tools/color/

Comment: I'm not sure why I can't answer this question so I'm posting it here.  In my naive opinion, any algorithm that hardcodes the specified seed color at 500 is incorrect. There's a StackOverflow question, [Material design color pallet][3], that discusses the same thing.  The correct answer in that question comes from [aytek][4].


  [3]: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32942503/material-design-color-palette
  [4]: https://stackoverflow.com/users/1259775/aytek

Answer (score 48, accepted):

I made this little CSS3/AngularJS tool for a project to generate Material Colors palettes. You can enter your 500 hex color and use an external tool like ColorZilla to get the color values from there. Also the lighter ones are exactly the ones Google used, but the darker ones are off by a little.

[mcg.mbitson.com](http://mcg.mbitson.com)

Comment: Your palette generator works really well, and as far as I can see, approximates the Google Material Design standards. One thing: you might want to create more contrast for the text on the page. The black text on the dark grey background is very hard to read.

Comment: Looking for the exact values Google generates with their palette. Used some of the code from your project: http://stackoverflow.com/q/32942503/1048340

Comment: Hey Guys! I'm the developer behind the updated version of the tool. I've recently be changing around the way I'm handling the color generation. If anyone has any direct feedback for this tool- it's color generation technique or any additional features they'd like, please let me know! I'm still developing enhancements in my spare time and I fear the color generation may be off, though still very helpful. I'll continue to look into it.

Comment: @MikelBitson The palette generator is indeed off (just enter any 500 colour from the material design standard and compare to see), however it works fantastic with many other base colours nonetheless. Keep up the great work!

Comment: @ChrisBornhoft Hey Chris! Thanks for the feedback, man. Yeah- I know they're off, but unfortunately this is truely unavoidable. Please see this issue thread for more information : https://github.com/mbitson/mcg/issues/19 Or this thread on stackoverflow for more information: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32942503/material-design-color-palette/33487476#33487476

Comment: @MikelBitson Fantastic explanation thanks. I figured it was something like this even before I posted my original comment. I wonder how much Google's "Official Colour Picker" makes? What a title :)

Comment: Great work!! You really should link the old version to the new version as it's just so much better. Thank you for this.

Comment: Updated link for those of you looking for the new version: http://mcg.mbitson.com/#/

Comment: I think your generated colors look good (in the updated version). I'm pretty sure the google pallet is hand tweaked otherwise they would expose their generator (unless it is really clever). I am building an app where the client enters a main color and a complimentary color and it generates the whole scheme on the front end. thanks for the sample code.

Answer (score 20):

The google palettes are [monochromatic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monochromatic_color). Which keeps the same RGB ratio shifting the Lightness and saturation up or down. To do this you have to convert the RGB value to HSL representation (Hue, Saturation, Lightness), alter the lightness and saturation then convert back if need be. It is possible to keep it in the RGB space while calculating, but the math is too confusing (for me to understand or explain). HSL was created for traditional color mixing (its easier for us to think about).

If your objective is to make CSS palettes you can keep the colour in HSL using `background-color: hsl(0,100%, 50%);`.

You can do this manually in Photoshop using the colour picker. The HSB is for Hue Saturation Brightness (Synonymous with HSL, same thing). Pick a hue you like and alter the Saturation and Brightness by a consistent value. In the image below S=54 and B=77, shift up by 5% using `54 + 54 * 0.05` and `77 + 77 * 0.05`. Or to shift down `S - S * 0.05`

[image: photoshop colour picker]

Side note to clarify between Hex & RGB. The 6 digit HEX #FFEB3B is actually 3 separate numbers, representing RGB.

`#FFEB3B -> FF,EB,3B -> red:FF green:EB blue:3B` converting the HEX values to decimal gives you `red:255 green:235 blue:59 OR rgb(255,235,59)`.

There are algorithms to convert RGB to HSL if you really want them on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hue#Computing_hue_from_RGB) but the simplest way is to use a colour lib. This example makes a monochromatic palette with [please.js](https://github.com/Fooidge/PleaseJS) it also has other algorithms for creating complementary or pleasing palettes. Much like kuler.adobe, which also rocks.

```
Please.make_scheme(
    Please.HEX_to_HSV('#ffeb3b'),
    {scheme_type: 'mono', format:'hex'}
);
// returns ->["#ffeb3b", "#ffe821", "#ffe508", "#e5d54c"]
```

Comment: Google's own palettes do not show a steady brighness gradient across HSV/HSB.  I've created an [illustration](http://malkyne.org/basement/images/colors/google_palette_brightness.png) so you can see what I'm talking about.  Based on that, you'd probably be better off playing with one of the other color models.

Additionally, they seem to have [tweaked their hue a little](http://malkyne.org/basement/images/colors/google_orange.png) for the darker shades of some colors, to keep them from getting muddy.

Comment: I would like to add a bit here that seconds @Tess's response.. I've developed the enhanced version of the MCG generator and in the process I've noticed a few things. Each google palette follows a different progression of colors, it is not monochromatic. There is no formula or method to mimic the colors exactly- as the formula for each palette ends up being completely different. More details and an example of this can be found here: https://github.com/mbitson/mcg/issues/19

Comment: @MikelBitson But in answer to the question 'what algorithm or process I can use' I would vote for monochromatic or a version of it https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monochromatic_color But you and Tess are right its not strictly mono, they deviate from the hue.

Comment: @Lex - I agree with you, I'd use monochromatic to estimate a palette. I only seconded Tess's response because your answer states that "The google palettes are monochromatic." and I have spent a good deal of time recently struggling with these colors. :)

Comment: HSB/HSV is not the same as HSL https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried working with Adobe's Color Wheel? I think it's a bit more flexible than the SlayerOffice tool you're using.

https://color.adobe.com/

For your exact case, choose "Shades" and try fooling around from there. It won't generate material-design like swatches, but it's a start.

Answer (score 0):

You could just download the palettes that Google give a link to on the site? Since it gives you all of the colors?

[Google Color Swatches Zip](http://quantum-paper.storage.googleapis.com/downloads/color_swatches.zip)

Comment: I think OP wanted to know how to start with his own color and generate a similar swatch

Answer (score 0):

To generate color gradient/palette from given color, essentially you can use following algorithm.

1. Decide minimum and maximum shade you want in your palette
2. Divide 'color-space' between these colors in equal partition (see below)
3. Output colors on these steps

For dividing color-space between, first you can convert color your HEX into RGB. Select values in each channel. Let's say you have *color1* (r1, g1, b1) and *color2* (r2, g2, b2). And you want 3 colors between *color1* and *color2*, then you can do something like following

```
all_colors = []
steps = no_of_colors + 1
rdelta, gdelta, bdelta = (r2 - r1) / steps, (g2 - g1) / steps, (b2 - b1) / steps
for step in range(steps - 1):
    r1 += rdelta
        g1 += gdelta
        b1 += bdelta
all_colors.append((r1, g1, b1))
```

Remember to convert RGB values between (0 to 1).

In your case, you can take base color and divide color space between `white to basecolor` and `basecolor to black`. You can adjust your steps according to your need.

Finally, I am going to do some shameless promotion of the python library I created, just because it is relevant to this question regarding color palette generation. It is called [SecretColors](https://github.com/secretBiology/SecretColors). You can generate own color palettes, gradients or use standard color palettes like IBM, Material Design, ColorBrewer or Clarity.