# How are Google Material Design Color Palettes Generated?

Tags: color-theory, google-material-design

I've searched a lot and did not find the expected result.

[Another Question here](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/37520/how-does-one-generate-a-palette-similar-to-the-ones-in-googles-material-design) says that  google palettes are *monochromatic*, but one single palette contains colors with different hue(though only small difference).

So does anyone know how exactly are Material Design Palettes generated? What is the pattern behind them? To be clearer, given a 500 primary color, how is the rest colors generated?

Comment: I think this question is a duplicate of the question you've linked and you'll find your answer there.

Comment: The answers in the linked question do not give **exact** pattern of generating the palette. For example 'Red 500' is '#f44336'(Hue: 3), but 'Red 400' is '#EF5350'(Hue: 1). It is not even monochromatic. So the answers in the linked question do not actually answer this question.

Answer (score 3):

There's no published algorithm, but it's latent in the code in the Material Design page [Color](https://material.io/inline-tools/color/). More specifically it's in the JS file [bundle.js](https://material.io/inline-tools/color/bundle.js).  The code is wildly obfuscated, likely the result of some kind of transpilation, but the algorithm is there.

There's a StackOverflow question, [Material design color pallet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32942503/material-design-color-palette), that discusses the same thing.  The correct answer in that question comes from [aytek](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1259775/aytek).

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at  [Hammwerk / material-color-palette](https://github.com/Hammwerk/material-color-palette).

It's a Java lib created by me to create such color palettes. The algorithm is reverse engineered from [Googles Color Palette Tool](https://material.io/design/color/the-color-system.html#tools-for-picking-colors).

First it calculates the difference between your custom color and each color in the "golden palettes" (the ones you can see on googles material color website). After that it takes the golden palette that contains the closest color to your custom one.

With this golden palette and the difference of your custom color to the one that is the closest one in the golden palette, it calculates each custom palette color.

Comment: Hi and welcome to GDSE! It seems you are linking to a tool created by yourself. Please edit your question so your affiliation with the tool is clear. It's mentioned [here](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/help/behavior). It would be nice if you could also explain the principle here on the site, but it might be too complicated or code related?